# Multiple comparisons correction in between-subject classification analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I am working with a dataset of 46 subjects (23 controls and 23 patients) fmri brain t-maps each with 4 experimental conditions. The main purpose of my analysis is to find the highest classification accuracy for patients vs controls discrimination which involves determining the best region and best experimental condition to do it.

I hypothesise (based on the fmri task and the concept underlying this project) that 6 regions-of-interest (ROIs) would be suitable to this classification analysis. Also, I think that not only the 4 conditions are worth investigate but also some linear combinations (contrasts) between them (eg. condition D - condition A, condition D - condition B, etc...). In sum, we have a total of 6 ROIs and 8 contrasts for each subject.

Assuming that I already chose a classifier (linear discriminant analysis) and cross-validation scheme I was thinking of performing the classification between patients and controls 48 times (8 contrasts in each ROI). Then, I would choose, for example, the 3 highest classification accuracies and run a permutation test on each one of them in order to calculate the p-values. After that I could correct for multiple comparisons using Bonferroni (0.05/3=0.017). My question is: Is this procedure statistically valid? If not, how should I do it?

I have tried to find similar designs in the literature but couldnt find any. I would be grateful if someone were kind enough to point papers reporting multiple comparisons correction on a classification analysis like this.

Comment: Well, it is often the case that one has to transform variables, e.g., take logs, reciprocals, exponentiate, square root, squares and so forth to find a best method for examining data. An alternative is to use nonparametric methods. So, how best to combine variables is contingent on what the characteristics of those variables are. For example, two variables, if equally influential, but very different in magnitude, would not be added or subtracted to combine them usefully.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Carl. However, I think you missed my point. I am not concerned about the linear combinations I chose since they make sense within the fmri task design. My main concern has to do with multiple comparisons in the context of classification analysis that is performed in several ROIs and several contrasts.

Comment: [Contrasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)), uh huh. Not the first thing that comes to mind for me. Why contrasts as compared to everything else? Your question concerns validity, and I am not following why you are doing what you are doing, so, kinda tough for me, at least, to answer.

Comment: I will try to clarify these contrasts. During the fmri task I provided 4 different levels of a stimulus to all subjects. Each level of that stimulus yielded a brain activation map for each subject. Now, since some linear combinations of these levels are important in the context of this experiment (level 4 - level 1, for example) I actually end up with 8 maps per subject. Using each one of this maps and each ROI I want to find the highest classification accuracy for patients vs controls. So I would be using the same classifier with the same cross-validation scheme 48 times.